# Referencing Ranges in Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have a code that turns cells white if they are gray, and stores that range in an array. Then I check each range in that array to see whether it is empty and the pattern is solid (white). If it is, then I turn it a lighter shade of gray. My code to test for this is currently

```
Dim Prev() As Range
'I also tried Prev() As Variant and have the same problem
Dim PrevCount As Long
Dim Counter As Long
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Interior.Pattern = xlGray50 Then
    Target.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    PrevCount = PrevCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Prev(1 To PrevCount)
    Set Prev(PrevCount) = Target
End If

For Counter = LBound(Prev) To UBound(Prev)
    If IsEmpty(Prev(Counter)) And Prev(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  Then
        Prev(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlGray25
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

No error occurs, but none of the ranges in the array that fulfill both criteria turn gray. I know nothing is wrong with the array, because it works just fine if I just do

```
For Counter = LBound(Prev) To UBound(Prev)
    If Prev(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  Then
        Prev(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlGray25
    End If
Next
```

So the

```
If IsEmpty(Prev(Counter))
```

Part does not work and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `IsEmpty` is returning `False` always, because it will return `True` only if variable is **not initialized**.

You need to do something else like a comparison to zero or empty string depending on your data. Best is you check this

```
Prev(Counter) = 0
```

assuming you are dealing with numerical quantities. That should work.

---

Reviewing the new code there are two points here. The Redim Preserve preserves all global data so it needs to be flushed empty (Redim to 0 elements) once your work is done.

Secondly, you should try setting

```
Dim Test as Integer
Test = CInt(Prev(x).Value)
if Test = 0 Then .... so on and so forth
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the variable is not initialized and it still doesn't work. Using your code returned an error mismatch. That's what I find odd because I tried dimensioning Prev as a range and variant, and both get mismatches

Comment: you could do a `CStr(Prev(Counter)) = ""`

Comment: Also, you may want to put a break-point in the loop, and see what value is returned by the IsEmpty(), most probably it's false. You may want to try the CStr first and lemme know?

Comment: Still a mismatch error. I put in a breakpoint but it doesn't return a value for the IsEmpty(), it only says "Counter = 1"

Comment: What kind of data is going in? numerical? string?

Comment: try `Len(Prev(Counter))= 0`

Comment: Also, what is the datatype? Variant?

Comment: It's just a range. The code should look at the range and, if it's empty and has a solid pattern, will execute a code. It can check whether it has a solid pattern, but not if it's empty.

Comment: Also try Prev(Counter).Value = 0

Comment: Pls post how the range is put here

Comment: still mismatch. I updated my post to show my entire code

Comment: OK. One major problem here. The Prev() variable is a global variable. SO now every time you redim preserve it, new stuff gets added to it without the old one being flushed out. That could cause issues down the line.

Comment: I actually do want to preserve the old ones because I want to check if any of the previous cells fulfill the criteria later. Still a mismatch error. I really appreciate all you help though

Comment: hmm... interesting. Works on my end. Could be an issue somewhere else in the code. Anyways, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **IsEmpty()** rather use:

```
If Prev(Counter) = "" And Prev(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  Then
```

or

```
If cStr(Prev(Counter).Value) = "" And Prev(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  Then
```

Comment: I tried, but it returns a type mismatch error. Thank you for your suggestion though

Comment: If you have **Dim'ed** *Prev()* as either *Integer* or *Long* or *Double* then use **cStr(Prev(Counter))**

Comment: It is Dim'ed as a Range. I edited my post to show my entire code. I also tried Variant with the same results